# Overriding managed version 9.4.1212.jre7 for postgresql

Tags: maven

While adding PostgreSQL Dependency to maven I have encountered the warning: Overriding managed version 9.4.1212.jre7 for postgresql. What does this mean?

Maven Dependency code:-

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this means is that the version for this dependency is already set in a parent pom. By setting the version in your pom, you are no longer using that "managed" version. You can remove the version element from your dependency to use the managed version, or continue with the version override as you have here.